# angular/ionic ng-click not updating the view, however it is updated in the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having serious difficulties updating a view in Ionic/Angular when using `ng-click`.

I came across a similar issue earlier on but solved it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191707/ng-click-wont-work-with-div-in-ionic) guidance, which explains that if your button is inside a `< label >` ng-click will not work.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I am developing a mobile application and want to allow a user edit their details if necessary. In an effort to start off most simply I have began by trying to implement the functionality whereby a user can edit their name. In the example below I am trying to change the name of the user when a button is clicked.

The strange thing is when I `console.log(Photos.name)` I get the correct value, i.e.(`scope.user.name = "Jim"`) however the view does not reflect this change.

The code I have is as follows:

**Controller**

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, Photos) {

    $scope.user = {
        "name": Photos.name
    }

    $scope.changeName = function() {
        Photos.changeName();
        console.log(Photos.name)
    };

})
```

**Factory**:

```
.factory('Photos', function(){
  var o = {
    name : 'James'
  }

  o.changeName = function(){
    o.name = 'Jim'
  }

  return o;

});
```

**HTML**
**Settings Template**

This is where the button is that updates the user's name on the profile.html page(see below)

```
 <ion-view view-title="Settings">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
       <div class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Change Profile Picture</span>
        <button type="button" ng-click="changeName()">Add</button>
      </div>
     </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

**Profile Template**

```
<ion-view view-title="My Profile">
  <ion-content class="padding"> 

   <div class="item item-body">
     <p class="profile-details">
        {{user.name}}
     </p>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I have read through many SO answers and those on the ionic webpage, with no luck. From what I have read I think that it may be something to do with setting the value in a child scope is the thing that is breaking it but I cannot be sure.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason is that once you do this:

```
$scope.user = {
    "name": Photos.name
}
```

You set the value of `$scope.user.name` to the value of `Photos.name` at *that moment*.

When you change `Photos.name` by doing `o.name = 'Jim'` within your factory, you're essentially assigning `Photos.name` a different string object, not changing the one that is already assigned to `$scope.user.name`.

You can prove my theory by doing something like `$scope.user = Photos` instead of `$scope.user = { ... }` (just as a quick proof of concept, of course, rather than a final solution). This way `$scope.user.name` will actually access the `name` value that's being held in the `Photos` factory.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it

Comment: Oops. I'm afraid it won't work. Strings in JavaScript are immutable. `replace` will only create a new one. But here's what should work: `$scope.user = Photos` instead of `$scope.user = { ... }` (just as a quick proof of concept, of course, rather than a final solution).

Comment: how do you mean ```$scope.user = Factory```? Are you aware of child scopes and angular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428042/angularjs-access-to-child-scope . Now I am not 100% sure of them hence why I am asking here, but I think it may be something to do with this

Comment: Fixed my comment. `Photos`, of course, not `Factory`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Bummer. Works for vanilla AngularJS though: http://jsfiddle.net/8NFJp/296/. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this, works on Ionic also. $scope.user = Photos; actually with ionic serve, not tried with emulator.

Comment: works after further investigation, thanks @SkyWriter

Comment: my pleasure, @PaulFitzgerald; updated the answer to be correct on its own right, without need to read the comments